# An RPG game with text graphics

Tags: java

I want to make a 2d MMO game, but instead of an actual graphic, the map and the character are represented by symbols such as, '#' for walls, '&' for the character you're controlling, '@' for the monsters, '$' for an unopened treasure, '_' for an opened one. The map has already been created in a text file, with all the other info (i.e, coordinates for a sign and its message, the location of the monster, teleport pads' coordinates, treasure chests coordinates, etc') To move the character, you simply write w/a/s/d in the console of the IDE and you can stack the movement controls such as ssswad. 'X' is for attacking, the MC can attack all around him. 'c' to interact. Every turn, the monsters are moving too and they try to follow your character. You have to find a crystal (whose location is prescribed in the file) to complete the level as well as killing every monster.

My question is, how do I load in the map and how would I edit the loaded map to put the monsters, the sign, the chests, the teleporter, etc.

According to a hint I got, there's a list of the monsters for each level. I attached a file as an example.

How the file is structured: monster: coordX, coordY, health, attackPower
teleporter: coordX, coordY, tpcoordX, tpcoordY.
When we quit(with 'q'), you save the level. The next time you come back, it will ask you if you want to continue.

Here's the code for my Level class:

```
public class Level {

    protected String levelName;
    protected Tile[][] level;
    protected ArrayList<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<>();

    public Level(String levelName) {
        this.levelName = levelName;
    }

    public void printLevel(){
        try {
        ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(levelName + ".txt"));
        String line = read.readLine();

        while (line != null){
            tempList.add(line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Cannot read file");
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. A line of code is worth a thousand words

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if you read his question, you would know that he is asking how to load the text file and do something with it (parse it).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for mention MUD, i didn't know what ot search for inspiration. Thank you

Comment: @ClamChowder please edit your question and put the code insiode not in comments

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this problem, but this is vaguely how I would do it.

Since you are reading the whole file to memory anyway, you can use NIO library to just do it:

```
String levelData = String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("level.txt")));
```

Easier than messing with streams in my opinion.

Now you have to decide what your in code data structures are. Everything has a coordinate I understand. And there can not me more than two items in one coordinate? Consider an interface:

```
interface Locatable {
    int getXCoordinate();
    int getYCoordinate();
}
```

Then perhaps some implementations like:

```
class Monster implements Locatable {
    // ...
}

class WallBlock implements Locatable {
    // ...
}

class Player implements Locatable {
    // ...
}

class TreasureChest implements Locatable {
    // ...
}
```

Then parse your string to those objects. To do that you can build a parser that goes something like this:

```
class LevelParser {
    public Level parse(String data) {
        Level level = new Level();
        String[] rows = data.split("\n")
        for (String row: rows) {
            String locatableType = row[0];
            int xCoord = Integer.parseInt(row[1]);
            int yCoord = Integer.parseInt(row[2]);
            if ("Monster".equals(locatableType)) {
                level.addMonster(new Monster(xCoord, yCoord));
            } else if ("Player".equals(locatableType)) {
                level.addPlayer(new Player(xCoord, yCoord));
            } // ... so on. Some of the objects may have special parsers because they have special properties
        }
        return level;
    }
}
```

Ant then you need to build some class which interacts with the level (mutates the level in accordance to players actions).
Some part of it may be something like this:

```
class Game {
    public gameLoop() {
        String userInput = "";
        while (!"q".equals(userInput)) {
            userInput = readNextUserInput();

            //.. interpret user input.
            // .. for the purpose of example its move left, then you would call
            level.movePlayerLeft();
            leverRenderer.render(level);
        }
    }
}
```

Where level render is a class which just System.out.println's all the level contents.

Inside the level class itself you can do your validations and mutations. Example

```
class Level {
    public void movePlayerLeft() {
        int playerCurrectX = player.getXCoord();
        int desiredX = playerCurrectX - 1;
        if (isFree(desiredX)) {
            // adjust player position
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Player can not move left as this spot is already occupied")
        }
    }
}
```

To sum it up there are a lot of building blocks to build a game nicely like this, but I hope this will get you going int the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have no idea how much this helps. Thanks again!!

Comment: Can you please explain to me what would the "implements Locatable" would do? I am a beginner and just got into OOP. Also, for the classes (i.e class Monsters). is that where I put their functions or do I call the functions from another class? The way I structured my code is I put an abstract class for Characters and as subclasses, I put the MC and Monsters, same for Tiles which envelops treasure, sign, etc...

Comment: I’m sorry but what an interface does and  how to correctly use it is way too much to explain in one StackOverflow answer. Abstract class is also an alternative option yes. P.S if my original answer helped you then please consider upvoting / accepting it. Also I would highly advise you to go through a few OOP tutorials about design patterns. This will surely go a long way for you

Comment: For the calsses WallBlocks, Treasure,etc would making them subclasses help? Like these would derive from the super class Tiles, and Tiles would implement 'Locatable'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the file using `FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("path");` and read it using  `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));` then you just loop thru the lines using `br.readLine()` and then just parse it into something usable: get text until some specific character as separator and get the number value.